# Javascript targeting issue

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a sharepoint page and I need to target the top menu header and the menu items.

But for some reason the  script does seem to want to know:

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4');
    var topNav = $get('zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4');
    alert(topNav);
    var links = topNav.getElementsByTagName('A');
    for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        var link = links[i];alert(link)
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4" class="s4-tn">
<div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
<ul class="root static">
<li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/sites/99991/SitePages/hold/highlights%20hold.aspx" accesskey="1"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">highlights hold</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/sites/99991/SitePages/promo/highlights%20promo.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">highlights promo</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/sites/99991/SitePages/live/action%20live.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">action live</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/sites/99991/SitePages/hold/action%20hold.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">action hold</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/sites/99991/SitePages/promo/action%20promo.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">action promo</span></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$get` But it does not seems that you are aware of use of jquery in this. If your intension is only to use javascript `getElementById(yourelementId)` is what you want.

Comment: OK i've sorted it - it was a timing issue - so just called it on the body onload - thanks anyway - peace